# Is "swinging left and right" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is "swinging left and right" idiomatic? Swinging means "to move laterally". I am not sure if I am wrong, but it just doesn't sound right and I don't imagine the phrase being used in a novel, so is there a more idiomatic way of saying this?

For example:

> Robert **swung his body left and right** on the bed as he never
>   experienced laying on a bed before since he had been homeless all his
>   life.

Comment: 'Swinging left and right' is more likely to be used politically in AmE. What do you mean by swinging on a bed? Unless it's a hammock, this is not idiomatic. Please include the dictionary definition of swing that you mean to use here.

Comment: The "idiomatic standard" for moving like this in a ***bed*** is [***tossed and turned***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/toss-and-turn). But as that link to Collins Dictionary says, *If you **toss and turn**, you keep moving around in bed and cannot sleep properly, for example **because you are ill or worried**.* So it wouldn't fit your *specific* context, where presunably Robert is [exuberantly, expansively] ***sprawling / stretching out / lounging*** on the bed (this being a novel "luxury" from his perspective).

Comment: This usage of "swing" is itself unidiomatic.  When you **swing** something, it's end is free and dangling in the air.  You could hang your arm or leg over the edge of the bed and **swing** that limb left and right through the air, but moving your body around in bed is not properly called **swinging**.

Comment: As the other comments are trying to suggest, **left and right** is fine. As would be ***tossed*** *his body* ***left and right***. The *overall* expression is idiomatic; however, the specific verb used is unusual and (without a contrived situation) not a good description of what is happening.

Comment: One of my pet peeves is mistaking "lay" and "lie." 99% of American readers will never notice, but 1% will groan at that "laying" instead of "lying."